# Why pixels can have float values?

Tags: opencv, floating-point, pixel, precision

this may be a simple question, but i wonder why pixel values can have float values? I'm tracking a target and get the mass center with contours() and moments() method and if i want i can get float values of them.

But why is this even possible? An image can't have a 0.1234 Pixel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `Mat` can hold `float` values, as well as many other types. Examples of images having float` values are:

- BGR images are typically in range `0, 255` for `uchar`, but in range `[0,1]` for `float`. It's just a convention.
- Your image is the result of some operation that produces `float` results. This is not necessarily a *ready-to-display* image, but in this case is just a regular matrix, holding some values. Don't forget that an image is just a matrix whose values represent the pixel values.

---

You can also have `float` coordinates. This is the case of *sub-pixel* accuracy. The centroid of a blob may have `float` coordinates. e.g. `(5.1, 6.8)`. You can draw this point loosing a bit of precision with integer coordinates, e.g. `(5, 7)`, but you may need the `float` value for further computation.

Answer (score 5):

I believe (if I did understand you properly) that you have discovered the world of [interpolation](http://www.cambridgeincolour.com/tutorials/image-interpolation.htm). An image itself, is a continous plane with `x` coordinates in the range of `[0, width]` and `y` coordinates in the range of `[0, height]`. To show the image in a monitor, or store it in disk, the image is discretized in pixels.

If you are applying discrete operations, such as convolutions, additions or thresholds to an image, it is normal to think of it as a grid of values. However, specially in your case that you are tracking objects in an image, you should think of it as a continuous space. The center of mass of a object, wont probably lay in a discrete value, it will be some floating point coordinate in the above range (i.e. `p = (50.5, 10.1)`), but that shouldn't be a problem.

If you want, you can also access the color (or gray-scale value) of the `p = (50.5, 10.1)` pixel by using [bilinear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation) (or more complex) interpolation.